# Plotting with yfinance package

Tags: python-3.x, plot, yfinance

In the following code, I want to plot the number of shares of company based on dates, e.g. YY-MM-DD. Using `yfinance`, the code looks like:

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker_symbol = 'MSFT'
stock = yf.Ticker(ticker_symbol)
s = stock.get_shares_full()
s = stock.get_shares_full(start="2023-01-01")
print(s)
     2023-01-04 00:00:00-05:00    7461940224
     2023-01-06 00:00:00-05:00    7454470144
     ...
     dtype: int64
dates=s.index
shares=s.values
plt.plot(dates, shares)
```

But the error is

```
ValueError: Multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is no longer supported. Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
```

How can I fix that with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will run using matplotlib versions greater that or equal to 3.6.

If however, this will fix the error:
`dates=s.index.to_numpy()`

Ref: [pandas.Index.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_numpy.html)